# OKTA: Best approach for authenticating users in custom web portal

Tags: python, authentication, okta, okta-api

I'm new to Okta and I'm having a tough time wrapping my head around what I need to do in order to authenticate users.

I'm writing a web portal for a company that already uses Okta internally.

They have requested that I use Okta to authenticate users. That is the only Okta integration requirement.

The portal uses vanilla JS/CSS/HTML5 on the front end, and a custom Python api layer and Python back end for serving data.

I've read through the guide over at http://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/pysaml2.html and I can't help but think this seems like overkill to simply authenticate users.

I saw that when I created a sample app that I could create the app with Secure Web Authentication rather than SAML. Is that advisable in my case? Do we need to use SAML?

If SAML is the correct approach, I'm feeling a bit lost after reading through the documentation about where to even begin. The app itself isn't really a Python app, although Python is used.

I have the Okta app created. I have the custom web app created with a custom Python backend and API layer.

Any tips on how to connect the two in order to authenticate users?

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this: http://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/okta_sign-in_widget

Seems most appropriate to your situation.

Comment: the code in this page calls the file https://ok1static.oktacdn.com/assets/js/sdk/okta-signin-widget/1.3.2/js/okta-sign-in-1.3.2.min.js
which is returning a 404.
I am assuming that there is a newer version?

Comment: There was a typo in the code sample. It will be fixed shortly. Substitute with 1.2.2 instead. The doc team apologized for the bug.